# Mathematical induction - the set version v.s. predicate version

Tags: logic, induction, set-theory, peano-axioms

There are two versions I know for mathematical induction, as well as structural induction. One says for all subset $S$ of $\Bbb N$, $1\in S\wedge (\forall n,~n\in S\rightarrow s(n)\in S)\rightarrow S=\Bbb N$. Another says for all predicate $P$ for natural numbers, $P(1)\wedge\forall n\in \Bbb N,~P(n)\rightarrow P(n+1)$ then $P$ is true for all $n\in\Bbb N$. I know traditionally the first is the original form. But some questions arise:

- Why some people preferred stated the latter version? Is it simply because of the pedagogical reason that mid-school students are more likely to understand the predicate version?
- In mathematical logic, which form is preferred? I roughly guess that the latter can not be easily written in first-order language? What is the role of  axiom schema of separation playing here?
- How to prove the equivalence of these two? What axioms and theorems do we need? Do we need the second-order language?

Comment: The second one, written as: $(P(1) ∧ ∀n \ (P(n)→P(n+1))) \to ∀n \ P(n)$ is expressible in first-order logic, and thus it is suitable for first-order arithmetic, where there is **no** $\in$ relation.

Comment: In set theory we can prove the first one, having available the $\in$ relation and having proved the existence of the set $\mathbb N$ as well as having defined the "initial"  number (usually : $0$) and the proxy for the *successor* relation $s(x) =_{def} x \cup \{ x \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Re: your first comment, one has to be extremely careful: **if** $P$ is a fixed formula in the relevant language, then the induction instance **for $P$ specifically** is first-order expressible, but "For all predicates $P$ for natural numbers, [induction]" is **not** first-order expressible since it involves quantifying over predicates.

Comment: @NoahSchweber - Correct... I've **not** quantified $P$.

Comment: Some people want to see how much math (e.g. number theory) they can do without using set theory. Not sure why.

Comment: @DanChristensen Probably because natural number logic is closely related to computation (a natural number is just the simplest recursively definable data structure), but set theory immediately starts defining uncomputable sets.

Comment: @DanielV Not sure why that is a problem, but set theory also allows you construct the real numbers and develop real analysis.